# how to replace content of a file in php with out concurrency issues

Tags: javascript, php

I want to append an HTML attribute  **id="active"** for a link of ***left.php***

*left.php* should have **only one link** with *id="active"*

The below code is actually working as per my requirement, but after a while the **content of left.php is totally missing** due to concurrency issues.

How can I resolve the issue?

I think we can have a java script solution for this to handle at client side.
Please let me know the best solution with example.

Thank you all.

```
<?php 
$searchF1  = ' id="active"';
$replaceW1 = '';
$searchF = basename(__FILE__).'"';
$replaceW = $searchF.' id="active"';

$myfile = fopen( 'left.php', 'rt' );
flock( $myfile, LOCK_SH );
$file = file_get_contents( 'left.php' );
fclose( $myfile );

$file = str_replace( $searchF1, $replaceW1, $file );
$file = str_replace( $searchF, $replaceW, $file );

file_put_contents('left.php', $file);

include('left.php');
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493438/synchronized-functions-using-php

http://php.net/manual/en/threaded.synchronized.php

Comment: I think better way is to use jQuery Try this

('#active').not(':first').remove();

Comment: Malith, can u please elaborate your approach, I would love to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to set the link of the current page as active. In this case you are doing it wrong. All the logic must be inside the `left.php` file. You can do it like this:

```
$pages = array(
    'firstPage.php'  => 'First Page',
    'secondPage.php' => 'Second Page',
    'thirdPage.php'  => 'Third Page',
);

$currentParsedUrl = parse_url("http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
$currentPath = ltrim($currentParsedUrl['path'], '/');

foreach ($pages as $path => $name) {
    echo '<a href="/' . $path . '"'; 
    echo $currentPath == $path ? ' id="active"' : '';
    echo '>' . $name . '</a>';
}
```

Now all you have to do is to include the `left.php` file wherever you want to display those links.

Comment: Thanks Matei Mihai, you made me think out of the box. I will try and let you all know.

Answer (score 0):

instead of file_put_contents and include try eval. Then you'll skip writting the file and use it as a template.

In the next version please try to use procedures or OOP.

Comment: Sure Richard, I am very glad for your valuable suggestion. Thanks a lot for taking time to answer. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

I did it with client side by adding the below **script** at the end of my **left.php**.

It is working, I think it is a good solution for the best performance. Thank you.

```
<script>
var name = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
var pattern = /.php/;
var exists = pattern.test(name);
if(exists){  $('a[href$="'+name+'"]').css('font-weight', 'bold');}
else{  $('#left').find('a:first').css('font-weight', 'bold');}  
</script>
```