# Synchronized block in php 7

Tags: php, multithreading, php-7

i come from a java background where there were synchronized blocks:

> The "Synchronized" keywords prevents concurrent access to a block of
>   code or object by multiple Threads.

example code in java:

```
public void addName(String name) {
    synchronized(this) {
        lastName = name;
        nameCount++;
    }
    nameList.add(name);
}
```

Now this example highlights a fundamental difference in php and java (correct me if i am wrong). But a singleton or shared class does not exist in php. So the given example of the java code makes a lot of sense when using as a singleton. Thus having a shared object between requests. Now this does not, sadly, seem to exist for php, a major disadvantage obviously. But to do it the php way, that would eventually be writing the name count into a file or database, thus having shared data between requests that way (a lot slower obviously). But the problem would be the same: if 2 requests increase the name count at the exact same time, it will be one too little.

Now the first question: does something similar exist for php 7? that is, the synchronized block

Now i am not sure if in php 7 the word thread really applies to what I am worried about. Is a thread in php considered to be as well a seperate call to a php file lets say `foo.php` that is, if I access `foo.php` at the same time twice, will the synchronized block if it exists, be executed only one after another, or do I have to create a proper php thread by extending the class `Thread` and only then it counts as thread?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem to me. For a database, can't you just do `count = count + 1` in the query? For a file, you could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronized functions using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493438/synchronized-functions-using-php)

Comment: PHP can benefit from multi-threading by using [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php), an API that allows multi-threading in PHP. This way you are able to perform a [synchronization lock](http://php.net/manual/en/threaded.synchronized.php) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is No, nothing like this exists for PHP because, as you point out PHP is does not run multi-threaded processes. PHP 7 is the same in this respect as previous PHP versions.

Now you describe the lack of multithreading as a major disadvantage. This isn't necessarily the case: it's a major *difference*. Whether it's a disadvantage or not is another question. That depends very much on context.

The problem you describe is of having shared object between processes. A shared object is a non-sequitur for PHP without the multi-threading, but the main point of a shared object is to share the *data* within the object.

If we're talking about shared data, you're right that a DB or file is a common way to do that, and is usually sufficient in terms of performance, but if you really need more performance you can genuinely share the data in memory by using something like Memcache. There are well-established libraries for dealing with memcache in PHP. This would be the normal PHP solution.

Now there are two other things I'd like to raise here that may be relevant here.

Firstly, let me add NodeJS to the equation, because this does things differently again. In NodeJS, the system is also single threaded, but unlike PHP which starts a new process for each request, in NodeJS all requests are fed into a single constantly-running thread. This means that in NodeJS, even though it's single-threaded, you can have global data (commonly the DB connection) that is shared between requests, because they're all running in the same process.

The point here is that being single-threaded isn't the reason why PHP can't share data between requests; it's more about the fact that in PHP each request is isolated from the others in its own process. Far from being a disadvantage, this can actually be an advantage -- for example, a PHP crash won't take down your entire site, where it could do in a multi-threaded or shared thread environment. In fact this is one of NodeJS's biggest weaknesses: it's quite easy for a single bit of poorly written code to make the server completely unresponsive.

The second thing I wanted to raise is that there are in fact experimental branches of PHP that do in fact allow you to use the language for both multi-threading and shared-thread environments. In both cases, these are very *very* experimental, and certainly should not be used for production. As you note in the question, the language is missing key features that would be necessary for use in these environments. But the fact is that it can be done.

Neither of these experiments is ever going to actually go anywhere because existing PHP code is not written with these kinds of environments in mind. You'll already know what happens if you write a multi-threaded Java program without protecting your shared data, so it should be clear that if PHP were ever to seriously entertain running in platforms with shared data then anyone wanting to use it with existing PHP code would need to do extensive rewriting. That's not just going to happen, so it's safe to say that PHP will stick with it's current format with isolated processes.

Comment: What do you mean by *global data* in Node.js?

Answer (score 7):

Other people answer with lots of words, but no code. Why don't you try this?

```
function synchronized($handler)
{
    $name = md5(json_encode(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS,1)[0]));
    $filename = sys_get_temp_dir().'/'.$name.'.lock';
    $file = fopen($filename, 'w');
    if ($file === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $lock = flock($file, LOCK_EX);
    if (!$lock) {
        fclose($file);
        return false;
    }
    $result = $handler();
    flock($file, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($file);
    return $result;
}

function file_put_contents_atomic($filename, $string)
{
    return synchronized(function() use ($filename,$string) {
        $tempfile = $filename . '.temp';
        $result = file_put_contents($tempfile, $string);
        $result = $result && rename($tempfile, $filename);
        return $result;
    });
}
```

The above code does an atomic `file_put_contents` using a custom "synchronized" function.

Source: https://tqdev.com/2018-java-synchronized-block-in-php

Answer (score 1):

PHP is designed to be shortlived - a PHP application is born and killed with an HTTP request.

Every time your webserver receives an HTTP request, it will invoke a new instance of your application. This instance lives in it's own process with it's own state.

This means that one request process cannot modify the state of another request process, but it also means that you don't have a built-in way to prevent two processes from executing the same code.

This means you have to design your application around this constraint.

Comment: that is very unsatisfying. I give you this example: paypal sometimes sends after each payment a confirmation TWICE at the exact same time. Now i do basically `if($confirmed && doesNotExistYet()){ $c = new Customer(); $c->save();}` guess what, when this gets executed without synchronize block, the whole thing will write two new customers instead of one. sorry, but that is bad

Comment: @Toskan Yes, but tat is nothing a `synchronized` statement would alleviate. You have to build your application different, e.g. by using `UNIQUE` constraints in your database.

Comment: @Polygnome this is actually the definition of the use case of the synchronized keyword. You obtain a lock on a piece of code and only one thread/process can access that code at a time. So `synchronized(foo){if($confirmed && doesNotExistYet())...}` would totally solve this problem. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No it would not. Because its *two different processes*. Javas `synchronized` does not cross process boundaries.

Comment: @Toskan You can obtain a lock INSIDE a process on one server with the synchronized keyword, but if you were to scale up your application to run in multiple servers - perhaps as part of a redundant setup - your solution would fail, because your lock would not be global.

Comment: @Toskan I don't know about PayPal's API, but if it included a transaction identifier, you could use this together with a uniqueness constraint. This will cause the second request by PayPal to fail.

Comment: @NielsB. good point, i haven't thought about scaling it up, true.

Comment: @Toskan - I ran into a similar issue with PayPal Adaptive checkouts redirecting customers multiple times.  I ended up utilizing the flock function to synchronize across multiple script invocations.  It sickens me that PHP doesn't have any proper synchronization capacity (that doesn't require a specially compiled binary).

Answer (score 1):

Singletons and shared classes *do exist* in PHP.

But PHP is short-lived. For every HTTP request, a new process is instantiated, and your script executed. This means that a `synchronized` kayword does not help in your case.

Race conditions between multiple requests are avoided by application design.

For exemple, in your SQL query, you would do things like `count = count + 1` instead of reading `count` first, then increasing it by one, and then writing. This is not that different then some mechanics you would employ in Java for concurrency (`synchronized` is often the *worst* cure for concurrency problems).

For databases, you can *lock* tables, and use *transactions* to ensure integrity over multiple queries.

> I give you this example: paypal sometimes sends after each payment a confirmation TWICE at the exact same time. Now i do basically if($confirmed && doesNotExistYet()){ $c = new Customer(); $c->save();}

Use UNIQUE constraints on your database. Or lock the table. Or else. You have options - but a `synchronized` keyword would not solve it, because those are *different processes*.

A word on singletons:
Java ensures that one singleton only exists once *per process*. PHP does the same. If you run the same JAR 2x you get two Java processes, each with its own instance of the singleton.

Comment: now i get what you meant with "synchronized would not solve it" yes, it won't solve it in a php context. I thought you were addressing java. Just seems a bit suboptimal to ensure concurrency using the DB. But i guess there is just no plan b for php. I was wondering if they changed something with php 7, but seems not like it

Comment: @Toskan a lot of things did change in PHP 7, but nothing quite as fundamental as the threading model - I doubt it would be possible to change that in a way that has sufficient backward compatibility to make it worthwhile.

Comment: @Polygnome how can i achieve concurrency saftey for say, edit of the customer? how would you do it for Orders? e.g. something that cannot rely on the unique constraint.

Comment: @Toskan You can do this in various ways, all of which are way too broad to be touched inside a comment here. People have written reliable PHP applications for ages, there is a lot of material available. RDBMs offer great tools to support consistency. In this case, I'd simply make one one, query for the update, which the RDBMS would ensure to be atomic.

Comment: hmm i was thinking a little bit, for the `Order` case where exist many orders per customer. Probably a good idea to avoid duplicates is using unique order ids per order as well that we create early on to avoid duplicates and cross reference when paypal calls the ipn handler